# Is $W$ a finite-dimensional vector space in Proposition 3.13?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image]

> Is $W$ a finite-dimensional vector space in Proposition $3.13$?

Comment: @JackLee It seems there isn't enough information about $W$ in $\textbf{ Proposition 3.13}$.

Comment: The tangent space was only defined for finite-dimensional smooth manifolds, so there is no need to explicitely state this.

Answer (score 1):

The author seems to assume that $W$ is a vector space and also a smooth manifold. So yes, it is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, and there is really no need to write down that explicitly.
The theorem states that there is a canonical isomorphism $V\cong T_aV$ when $V$ is finite-dimensional, so in writing $W\cong T_{La}W$ it is implicitly assumed that $W$ is finite-dimensional as well as it is using this canonical isomorphism for $W.$